# obj c class memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have extended UIView in order to implement some unique functionality. Along with this, I have included several objects as properties and defined them in the initialiser as defaults. This means that every object that extends this class, Graphics.m, will have these objects instantiated and available, things like default interface colours.

My question is, if I have a large number of objects, will the fact I have these defaults instantiated in every object (they may go unused in some objects) seriously affect the app's performance?

I am running the latest versions of Xcode and iOS.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you're writing massive base classes, then yes, space for those properties will get `malloc()`'d onto the heap when the other objects are created.  But why even write massive base classes in the first place?

Comment: The Base class isn't that massive. It just stores a few defaults and some specialised initialisers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a large number of objects, will the fact I have these defaults instantiated in every object (they may go unused in some objects) seriously affect the app's performance?

It depends on the size of these properties and whether the frameworks internally cache instances.

What you could do in your case is to keep defaults in variables with static storage duration and have your properties point to those variables when an instance is initialised. In this case, if those properties aren’t changed after initialisation then they all point to the same objects. For example:

```
// ARKGraphicsView.m

static UIColor *_ARKGraphicsViewDefaultForegroundColour = nil;
static UIColor *_ARKGraphicsViewDefaultBackgroundColour = nil;
static UIColor *_ARKGraphicsViewDefaultBorderColour = nil;

@implementation ARKGraphicsView

+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [ARKGraphicsView class]) {
        // This code is executed only once,
        // when the class receives its first message
        _ARKGraphicsViewDefaultForegroundColour = [UIColor …];
        _ARKGraphicsViewDefaultBackgroundColour = [UIColor …];
        _ARKGraphicsViewDefaultBorderColour = [UIColor …];
    }
}

- (id)initWith… {
    self = [super initWith…];
    if (self) {
        _foregroundColour = _ARKGraphicsViewDefaultForegroundColour;
        _backgroundColour = _ARKGraphicsViewDefaultBackgroundColour;
        _borderColour = _ARKGraphicsViewDefaultBorderColour;
    }
    return self;
}

…

@end
```

If the program creates 100 instances of this class and no colours are changed by those instances, there will be only three `UIColor` instances—those kept in the `_ARK*Colour` variables.

Comment: OK Thanks, that's a great solution. So, just to clarify, +initialize is only called once ever when the app starts up?

Comment: It's called when the class is instantiated the first time.

Comment: @arkaeologic The Objective-C runtime sends `+initialize` to the class when the class receives its first message (for example, when its first instance is allocated via `+alloc`), which is not necessarily when the application starts. There is another class method called `+load` that gets executed when the class is loaded by the runtime, which tipically means when the program is loaded on iOS. Note that `+initialize` is sent multiple times, once for each class in the class hierarchy (i.e., once for the class and once for each superclass), which is why developers should test the current class.